# Почему иконка приложения отображается по-разному?

Tags: wpf, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, icon

Есть приложение на C#/WPF. Решил сделать для него иконку. Конвертировал `.bmp` в `.ico`, в свойствах проекта указал иконку. Всё заработало, как и ожидалось. Позже понадобилось сменить иконку. Проделал те же действия с новой иконкой **и вот тут началось интересное**:

1. Собираю под Win32 и x64 – под второй иконка заменяется, под первой остаётся прежней.
2. Удаляю файлы со старой иконкой из всех возможных расположений. Пересобираю – то же самое. `.exe` собранный под х64 с новой иконкой, под  Win32 – со старой.
3. Дальше веселее – захожу в папку с `.exe`-файлом, у которого иконка не заменилась. Копирую его в другое расположение. **Иконка копии меняется на новую**. Просто после копирования.
4. Теперь ещё немного интереснее. Всё в той же папке выделяю `.exe` и делаю Ctrl+C  и сразу же там же Ctrl+V. **И иконка у копии меняется на новую, а у исходного файла остаётся старой**
5. При переименовании исполняемого файла у файла с новым именем отображается новая иконка. При переименовании обратно иконка возвращается.
6. И, наконец, при перемещении на другой компьютер иконка всё же остаётся старой. Прочие манипуляции на другом компьютере не производились.

В общем, по всей видимости, ОС как-то привязывает иконку к имени файла. Именно к имени, а не содержимому.

Логичный вопрос: что за магия происходит и как от этого всё-таки избавиться? (я понимаю, что этому есть рациональное логичное объяснение, но я его не нашёл, увы).

Comment: Это кэширование винды. Как сбросить кэш можно найти в Гугле. Увы, винда не ожидает, что у приложения будет меняться иконка, поэтому извлекает ее один раз при первом сканировании и помещает в кэш, ключом является путь к файлу, поэтому, при копировании, приложение будет просканировано снова и иконка будет уже актуальная